# Rails how to configure rspec so you do not need to require "rails_helper"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

title says it all mostly. Given new Rails app and rspec-rails. If I app an `app/lib/foo.rb` class. How do I configure rspec to be loaded so I do not have to do this:

```
# spec/lib/foo_spec.rb
require "rails_helper"

describe Foo do
end
```

Comment: YAGNI. Its automatically added when you use the generators and adding it to the configuration would cause it to be loaded in all your specs - even lightweight specs that don't need the whole rails stack when run on thier own.

Answer (score 3):

In the .rspec file at the root of the project, add

```
--require rspec_helper
```

on its own line. The rspec command adds any options in this file automatically when run.

Comment: You don't want to do this with `rails_helper.rb` though as this would require Rails in all your specs.

Answer (score 0):

Just type in your terminal(project root folder):

```
echo --require rails_helper > .rspec
```